# JMeter throughput results differ although average is similar

Tags: jmeter

Ok so I ran some stress tests on an application of mine and I came across some weird results compared to last time.
The **Throughput** was way off although the averages are similar.

The number of **Samples** did vary, however as I understood the **Throughput** is calculated by dividing the number of samples by the time it took.
In my understanding if the average time was similar the throughput should be similar even though the samples varied...

This is what I have:

**PREVIOUS**
[image]

**RECENT**
[image]

As you can see the **throughput** difference is pretty substantial...

Can somebody please explain me if my logic is correct or point me on why that is not the case?

Comment: Did you use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) in your script to measure **Throughput**? To get expected throughput you have to generate enough number of threads too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Throughput** is the number of requests per unit of time (seconds, minutes, hours) that are sent to your server during the test.

The **throughput** is the real load processed by your server during a run but it does not tell you anything about the performance of your server during this same run. This is the reason why you need both measures in order to get a real idea about your server’s performance during a run. The response time tells you how fast your server is handling a given load.

The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.

> Throughput =(number of requests) / (total time).

**Average:** This is the **Average** (Arithmetic mean μ = 1/n * Σi=1…n xi) **Response time** of your total samples.It is the arithmetic mean of all the samples response time.

**Response time** is the elapsed time from the moment when a given request is sent to the server until the moment when the last bit of information has returned to the client.

So these are two different things.

> Think of a trip to Disney or your favorite amusement park. Let's
>   define the capacity of the ride to be the number of people that can
>   sit on the ride per turn (think roller coaster). **Throughput** will
>   be the **number of people that exit the ride per unit of time**. Let's
>   define service time -the amount of time you get to sit on the ride.
>   **Response time** to be your **time queuing for the ride
>   plus service time**.

Comment: So the number of requests should in fact not affect the throughput at the end correct?
It seems I have to find out why this was the case than... thanks for the explanation

Comment: @fditz, I think, you don't have enough number of threads. Share your script details (number of threads, durations,etc). It seems you have run your scripts for different time durations.